# How can I combine objects in the Raphael javascript library?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Sorry for a long question but here goes.  I am trying to modify the drag shapes around demo here:

http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

The demo works fine.  What I want to do is put words inside the shapes and move the shape and text around as a composite single object.

Here is the code for creating the objects:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var dragger = function () {
        this.ox = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("x") : this.attr("cx");
        this.oy = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("y") : this.attr("cy");
        this.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);
    },
        move = function (dx, dy) {
            var att = this.type == "rect" ? {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy} : {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy};
            this.attr(att);
            for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
                r.connection(connections[i]);
            }
            r.safari();
        },
        up = function () {
            this.animate({"fill-opacity": 0}, 500);
        },
        r = Raphael("holder", 640, 480),
        connections = [],
        shapes = [  r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20),
                    r.rect(290, 80, 60, 40, 10),
                    r.rect(290, 180, 60, 40, 2),
                    r.ellipse(450, 100, 20, 20)
                ];
    for (var i = 0, ii = shapes.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var color = Raphael.getColor();
        shapes[i].attr({fill: color, stroke: color, "fill-opacity": 0, "stroke-width": 2, cursor: "move"});
        shapes[i].drag(move, dragger, up);
    }
    connections.push(r.connection(shapes[0], shapes[1], "#fff"));
    connections.push(r.connection(shapes[1], shapes[2], "#fff", "#fff|5"));
    connections.push(r.connection(shapes[1], shapes[3], "#000", "#fff"));
};
```

I tried something like this:

```
 myWords = [ r.text(190, 100,  "Hello"),
      r.text(480,100, "Good Bye")
    ];
```

and made adjustments elsewhere so that it would work, but then it just moves text and shapes but the shape and text are never seen as a whole.  I can move the text separate from the shape and vice versa.  I need them to be one object. so they move together. How can I do that?  Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
  st.push(r.text (190, 100, "node1"), r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20)),
  st.push(r.text (290, 80, "Center"), r.rect(290, 80, 60, 40, 10)),
  st.push(r.text (290, 180, "node2"), r.rect(290, 180, 60, 40, 2)),
  st.push(r.text (450, 100, "node3"), r.ellipse(450, 100, 20, 20))
```

But the text and shape did not stay together when I moved the shape.  The text just stayed still.

EDIT:  I cannot get the stock demo at http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html to work with Chrome.  IE it works.

Comment: You don't move the shape. You move the set. Treat the set as a single shape that happens to contain the text and rect.

Comment: @slebetman - How would you do this? There's no way to click on a set to select it to move, since sets don't have associated DOM elements. - @johnny - Instead of a complicated method using sets, you can just pair the elements using a custom property. - See my answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

*Did major edit to associate elements in a more elegant way.*

---

**[Sets](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#set)** are good for grouping Raphael objects, but sets do not create their own elements, so you cannot drag and drop a set, since when you click on the canvas you either select the shape or the text, but never the set (since there is no set element).

**[Here is a simple jsFiddle showing the properties of a set.](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ahW/)** Note that a set has no `x` or `y` properties.

From the **[Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)**:

> [A set c]reates array-like object to keep and operate couple of elements at once. **Warning: it doesn’t create any elements for itself in the page.**

The simple work around is to make both the text and shape separately draggable. Then move the associated text along with the shape... and the associated shape along with the text.

Associating objects like this is simple... create a property. In this case each shape and each text has a property called `.pair` which is a reference to the associated element.

Here's how it's done:

```
var i, ii, tempS, tempT
     shapes = [  ... ],
     texts = [  ... ];
for (i = 0, ii = shapes.length; i < ii; i++) {
    tempS = shapes[i].attr( ... );
    tempT = texts[i].attr( ...);

      // Make all the shapes and texts dragable
    shapes[i].drag(move, dragger, up);
    texts[i].drag(move, dragger, up);

      // Associate the elements
    tempS.pair = tempT;
    tempT.pair = tempS;
}
```

And then in the drag and drop code, which is the `move()`, `dragger()`, and `up()` functions you have to make sure to deal with both the clicked on element and its associated element.

For example here is the pertinent part of the `move()` function. Note that `text` can be dealt with in the same way as `rectangle` (by changing attributes `x` and `y`), so the `false` condition in each of the Javascript conditional operators below handles both the case for `rectangle` and for `text`

```
move = function (dx, dy) {

      // Move main element
    var att = this.type == "ellipse" ? 
                           {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy} : 
                           {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy};
    this.attr(att);

      // Move paired element
    att = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? 
                            {cx: this.pair.ox + dx, cy: this.pair.oy + dy} : 
                            {x: this.pair.ox + dx, y: this.pair.oy + dy};
    this.pair.attr(att);
    ...
}
```

And below is the full working code:

### **[Working jsFiddle example of draggable text and shapes](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/)**

```
Raphael.fn.connection = function (obj1, obj2, line, bg) {
    if (obj1.line && obj1.from && obj1.to) {
        line = obj1;
        obj1 = line.from;
        obj2 = line.to;
    }
    var bb1 = obj1.getBBox(),
        bb2 = obj2.getBBox(),
        p = [{x: bb1.x + bb1.width / 2, y: bb1.y - 1},
        {x: bb1.x + bb1.width / 2, y: bb1.y + bb1.height + 1},
        {x: bb1.x - 1, y: bb1.y + bb1.height / 2},
        {x: bb1.x + bb1.width + 1, y: bb1.y + bb1.height / 2},
        {x: bb2.x + bb2.width / 2, y: bb2.y - 1},
        {x: bb2.x + bb2.width / 2, y: bb2.y + bb2.height + 1},
        {x: bb2.x - 1, y: bb2.y + bb2.height / 2},
        {x: bb2.x + bb2.width + 1, y: bb2.y + bb2.height / 2}],
        d = {}, dis = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 4; j < 8; j++) {
            var dx = Math.abs(p[i].x - p[j].x),
                dy = Math.abs(p[i].y - p[j].y);
            if ((i == j - 4) || (((i != 3 && j != 6) || p[i].x < p[j].x) && ((i != 2 && j != 7) || p[i].x > p[j].x) && ((i != 0 && j != 5) || p[i].y > p[j].y) && ((i != 1 && j != 4) || p[i].y < p[j].y))) {
                dis.push(dx + dy);
                d[dis[dis.length - 1]] = [i, j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (dis.length == 0) {
        var res = [0, 4];
    } else {
        res = d[Math.min.apply(Math, dis)];
    }
    var x1 = p[res[0]].x,
        y1 = p[res[0]].y,
        x4 = p[res[1]].x,
        y4 = p[res[1]].y;
    dx = Math.max(Math.abs(x1 - x4) / 2, 10);
    dy = Math.max(Math.abs(y1 - y4) / 2, 10);
    var x2 = [x1, x1, x1 - dx, x1 + dx][res[0]].toFixed(3),
        y2 = [y1 - dy, y1 + dy, y1, y1][res[0]].toFixed(3),
        x3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, x4, x4, x4 - dx, x4 + dx][res[1]].toFixed(3),
        y3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, y1 + dy, y1 - dy, y4, y4][res[1]].toFixed(3);
    var path = ["M", x1.toFixed(3), y1.toFixed(3), "C", x2, y2, x3, y3, x4.toFixed(3), y4.toFixed(3)].join(",");
    if (line && line.line) {
        line.bg && line.bg.attr({path: path});
        line.line.attr({path: path});
    } else {
        var color = typeof line == "string" ? line : "#000";
        return {
            bg: bg && bg.split && this.path(path).attr({stroke: bg.split("|")[0], fill: "none", "stroke-width": bg.split("|")[1] || 3}),
            line: this.path(path).attr({stroke: color, fill: "none"}),
            from: obj1,
            to: obj2
        };
    }
};

var el;
window.onload = function () {
    var color, i, ii, tempS, tempT,
        dragger = function () {
                // Original coords for main element
            this.ox = this.type == "ellipse" ? this.attr("cx") : this.attr("x");
            this.oy = this.type == "ellipse" ? this.attr("cy") : this.attr("y");
            if (this.type != "text") this.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);

                // Original coords for pair element
            this.pair.ox = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? this.pair.attr("cx") : this.pair.attr("x");
            this.pair.oy = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? this.pair.attr("cy") : this.pair.attr("y");
            if (this.pair.type != "text") this.pair.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);            
        },
        move = function (dx, dy) {
                // Move main element
            var att = this.type == "ellipse" ? {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy} : 
                                               {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy};
            this.attr(att);

                // Move paired element
            att = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? {cx: this.pair.ox + dx, cy: this.pair.oy + dy} : 
                                               {x: this.pair.ox + dx, y: this.pair.oy + dy};
            this.pair.attr(att);            

                // Move connections
            for (i = connections.length; i--;) {
                r.connection(connections[i]);
            }
            r.safari();
        },
        up = function () {
                // Fade original element on mouse up
            if (this.type != "text") this.animate({"fill-opacity": 0}, 500);

                // Fade paired element on mouse up
            if (this.pair.type != "text") this.pair.animate({"fill-opacity": 0}, 500);            
        },
        r = Raphael("holder", 640, 480),
        connections = [],
        shapes = [  r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20),
                    r.rect(290, 80, 60, 40, 10),
                    r.rect(290, 180, 60, 40, 2),
                    r.ellipse(450, 100, 20, 20)
                ],
        texts = [   r.text(190, 100, "One"),
                    r.text(320, 100, "Two"),
                    r.text(320, 200, "Three"),
                    r.text(450, 100, "Four")
                ];
    for (i = 0, ii = shapes.length; i < ii; i++) {
        color = Raphael.getColor();
        tempS = shapes[i].attr({fill: color, stroke: color, "fill-opacity": 0, "stroke-width": 2, cursor: "move"});
        tempT = texts[i].attr({fill: color, stroke: "none", "font-size": 15, cursor: "move"});
        shapes[i].drag(move, dragger, up);
        texts[i].drag(move, dragger, up);

        // Associate the elements
        tempS.pair = tempT;
        tempT.pair = tempS;
    }
    connections.push(r.connection(shapes[0], shapes[1], "#fff"));
    connections.push(r.connection(shapes[1], shapes[2], "#fff", "#fff|5"));
    connections.push(r.connection(shapes[1], shapes[3], "#000", "#fff"));
};​
```

---

For completeness here is the code for **[the linked to jsFiddle for showing the properties of a set](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ahW/)**:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 320, 200),
        st = paper.set(), 
        propArr = [];

    st.push(
        paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
        paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
    );

    st.attr({fill: "red"});

    for(var prop in st) {
        if (st.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            // handle prop as required
            propArr.push(prop + " : " + st[prop]);
        }
    }
    alert(propArr.join("\n"));
};​

// Output:
// 0 : Raphael's object
// 1 : Raphael's object
// items : Raphael's object,Raphael's object
// length : 2
// type : set
```

Comment: Here's a slightly more generic solution that requires a patch I wrote against Raphael to allow for named sets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277129/raphael-js-how-to-use-jquery-selectors-on-objects-in-ie/6944372#6944372 - instead of cross calling, you can access the other members of the set from element in the event callback. Thanks for the great work, Peter; my solution was directly inspired by this answer.

Comment: I don't know why these no longer work in Chrome but oh well.  Still works good in IE.

Comment: i guess,  it would be better to just paste the link to the example on raphael site (http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) then getting all the code from there to paste it here and jsfiddle

Answer (score 7):

Or, try this "group" plugin for Raphael which lets you create a proper SVG  group element.

https://github.com/rhyolight/Raphael-Plugins/blob/master/raphael.group.js

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's what the `set` object is for:

```
var myWords = r.set();
myWords.push(
    r.text(190, 100, "Hello"),
    r.text(480,100, "Good Bye"
);

// now you can treat the set as a single object:
myWords.rotate(90);
```

---

*Additional answer:*

OK, I see that you've tried using set but you are using it wrong. A set creates a group of things. Just like if you were to group shapes and text in Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape or Microsoft Word or Open Office. If I understand you correctly what you want is this:

```
shapes = [  r.set(r.text (190, 100, "node1"), r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20)),
            r.set(r.text (290, 80, "Center"), r.rect(290, 80, 60, 40, 10)),
            r.set(r.text (290, 180, "node2"), r.rect(290, 180, 60, 40, 2)),
            r.set(r.text (450, 100, "node3"), r.ellipse(450, 100, 20, 20))
         ];
```

You'll also have to modify your dragger and move functions since the shapes are no longer of type 'rect' but are of type 'set':

```
var dragger = function () {
    this.ox = this.attr("x");
    this.oy = this.attr("y");
    this.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);
};
var move = function (dx, dy) {
    var att = {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy};
    this.attr(att);
    for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
        r.connection(connections[i]);
    }
    r.safari();
};
```

All sets have `x` and `y` attributes.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, it did not work.  I can move the shapes but not the text.  I changed all that you said.  For the moment all I know to do it just have the r.text without shapes.  I do appreciate your help.

Comment: The problem with this method is that sets do not create any elements on the page, so when you click for a drag and drop you won't select the set, but only the element.... so `this` in `dragger` is referring to one element and not the set.

Comment: `Sets` do not have a collective `x` and `y`. Actions on a `set` are applied to each individual in the set. The `set` is not treated as a whole. ----------- `myWords.rotate(90);` doesn't rotate the `set` as a whole. It simple iterates over each object in the set and rotates those ==> http://jsfiddle.net/UFxJZ/ (note that the 2 words started parallel on 2 separate lines.... after rotation they are now parallel but on the same line!)

Comment: we have two answers that seem to contradict the other.  one says that a set WILL allow you to move objects in unison and another that says a  set WILL NOT allow that functionality.  can we get a definitive answer as to which answer is correct?  they can't both be right can they?  they both have upvotes however

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier just to change the attributes of the paired object along with the attributes which are changing when the main object is dragged?

Something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var R = Raphael("holder"),
            circ = R.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({ "fill": "#d9d9d9", "stroke-width": 1 }),
        circ2 = R.circle(50, 50, 5),
            start = function () {
                this.ox = this.attr("cx"); //ox = original x value
                this.oy = this.attr("cy");
                this.animate({ "opacity": .5, "stroke-width": 15 }, 200);
            },
            move = function (dx, dy) {  //dx - delta x - diiference in movement between point a and b
                var cdx = circ2.attr("cx") - this.attr("cx"),
                    cdy = circ2.attr("cy") - this.attr("cy");
                this.attr({ "cx": this.ox + dx, "cy": this.oy + dy });
                group(this,circ2,cdx,cdy);
                R.safari();
            },
            up = function () {
                this.animate({ "opacity": 1, "stroke-width": 1 }, 200);
            },
            group = function (refObj,thisObj, dx, dy) {                    
                thisObj.attr({ "cx": refObj.attr("cx") + dx, "cy": refObj.attr("cy") + dy });
            };

            circ.drag(move, start, up);




    };
```

Comment: If you only call drag on one of the grouped elements and they have overlapping boundaries, the "sidecar" elements may get the mouse event and not allow the primary element to be dragged.  Using toFront() didn't solve that for me but calling drag on all in the group worked well.